# How can I repeat a function if there's an error message?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a function that checks if an input value is within a range, but I get an error message if a string is input. I want the function to repeat, essentially ask the question again instead of just giving an error message.

I expected the code to repeat but I am still getting an error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSHuq.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)